# Binding to parent datacontext to work with a PropertyChangedEventHandler

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm having difficulties on updating a listbox with a change in the list it is bound to.
The main window has the datacontext set through code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ConfigurationListViewModel _ConfListVM;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        _ConfListVM = new ConfigurationListViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _ConfListVM.ConfList;
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ConfigMng.CreatedConfigurationEvent += new EventHandler(OnCreateConfiguration);
    }

    void OnCreateConfiguration(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _ConfListVM.Add("Test");
    }

}



public class ConfigurationListViewModel
{
    public ConfigurationList ConfList = new ConfigurationList();
}

public class ConfigurationList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Configuration> _ObservableConfList = new ObservableCollection<Configuration>();
    public ObservableCollection<Configuration> ObservableConfList { get { return _ObservableConfList; } set { _ObservableConfList = value; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    public ConfigurationList()
    {
        ObservableConfList.Add(new Configuration("aaa"));
        ObservableConfList.Add(new Configuration("bbd"));
    }


    public void Add(Configuration Conf)
    {
        ObservableConfList.Add(Conf);
        OnPropertyChanged(Conf.ConfName);
    }
}
```

}

In the Main Window XAML I set the User Control:

```
<GroupBox Header="Configurations" >
    <local:ConfigurationMng x:Name="ConfigMng"/>
</GroupBox>
```

And in the ConfigurationMng I have the following ListBox, that I bound to the list `ConfList`

`<ListBox Name="lbConfigurationList" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableConfList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">`

I can see correctly in the ListBox the 2 element I created with the constructor, but when I manually add another element, PropertyChanged is always null.

I think I understood that I have to set a DataContext (but I thought that if not manually specified, it should use its parent one);

I tried then to set it manually:

```
<ListBox Name="lbConfigurationList" DataContext="{Binding [??????], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableConfList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
```

but I got stuck on understanding on what should I bind it.
Am I now in MainWindow's datacontext? So i'm in the scope `_ConfList.ConfList`? I should write just `Binding` and I should be in the correct DataContext, right?

Nope, even the manually added Configurations disappear.

What am I missing here?

Edit: ConfigurationMng's CodeBehind:

```
public partial class ConfigurationMng : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler CreatedConfigurationEvent;

    public ConfigurationMng()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddConfiguration(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Called with a button pression
    {
        if (this.CreatedConfigurationEvent != null)
        {
            this.CreatedConfigurationEvent(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Solved, the problem seems that the main ConfigurationListViewModel wasn't implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, so he just wasn't notifying the listbox of the change.
I can't write the actual solution since I rewrote this part of the project

Answer (score 0):

**You are correct that it will inherit the parent's `DataContext`.**

```
<ListBox Name="lbConfigurationList" DataContext="{Binding [??????], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableConfList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
```

Since your assumption that parent datacontext is inherited, you don't need to explicitly set the `DataContext` for `ListBox`. You just need to make sure that your ItemsSource is defined like this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ConfList.ObservableConfList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
```

You are binding to an `ObservableCollection` which you don't need `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModel because the collection alreay takes care of that. If you want to handle the added/deleted elements then you can use the `CollectionChanged` of the collection.

Also, your Model `Configuration` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you would want to listen on each item.

From what I can see, your architecture is adding more complexity. Why did you need to create a separate class just to have an `ObservableCollection`? You can just put it in the ViewModel and leave your `Configuration` as your model.

Comment: Something doesn't seems right... if the PropertyChanged is null, doesn't that mean that the DataContext is null? The logger too says that

Comment: `You are correct that it will inherit the parent's DataContext.` He's a doing a RelativeSource binding back to window which will set the window itself as the DC. If you want to inherit the DC with a RelativeSource then you have to specify it explicitly with `<ListBox DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableConfList...`

Comment: Also, i inserted the ConfigurationList in the ViewModel because I thought that was the correct way to incapsulate all the model; but if you say it's overkill ok then, I'll just insert there the ObservableCollection<Configuration>.

Comment: and I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on the ConfigurationList because I thought this way I could notify every property change in its elements; was I wrong?

Comment: @MarkFeldman: now I could see the constructed elements again, but the PropertyChanged is still null.  I think I made somehing else wrong...

Comment: There's no reason why this code shouldn't be working, it must be something in the child control that you haven't posted yet.

Comment: @MarkFeldman I was referring to when he did not set the DC for the control without the RelativeSource.

Comment: @user1722791 No. It doesn't mean DataContext is null. You can implement `INPC` and PropertyChanged` won't be null because you can call a method that raises it. Can you give me a reproduction project ?

Comment: I decided to do some clean up after a bit better understanding of mvvm, when I'll come back to this part if I have again the problem I'll update the question; thanks anyway

Comment: ...it seems the ConfigListViewModel wasn't implementing the INPC